# Can't connect spring boot app running in docker container in google app engine to google cloud sql?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have spring boot application, that works in docker container, and database configuration is quiet simple:

```
spring:
   datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://35.225.172.41/postgres
    username: root
    password: somePassword
```

Docker file is also simple as possible:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:slim

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I find out how to access database when I run application locally. I add my local machine IP address to Authorized networks, and if I run my application locally in docker I have access to google cloud SQL, also can connect to it with DataGrip. But when I deploy my application to google app engine it's can't connect to the database. How can I grant permission to my application to get access to google cloud sql? I dried also add application IP address to authorized networks but IP address is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach of solving this problem was absolutely wrong. To have an access to google cloud slq I had to use spring-cloud-gcp.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/main/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-postgres-sample

All I need is to add required dependencies (in my case :

```
 dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:1.2.8.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql'
```

create google cloud API key .json
and set up application.yml properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location 'file:/api_key.json'
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name: postgres
spring.datasource.username: someUsername
spring.datasource.password: somePass
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name: proj-name:region:slq-instance-name
```

Database URL is not needed, spring cloud gcp will create it and connect your application to cloud database.